# Toggle Buttons, failed assertion line 188 pos 12: 'isSelected != null is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, togglebutton

I am currently learning Flutter and I try to make a text ToogleButtons, But I got this error :

```
'package:flutter/src/material/toogle_buttons.dart': Failed assertion: line 188 pos 12: 'isSelected != null': is not true.
```

I've changed the bool of list `isSelected` to `[true, false, false];` but it didn't work,

My code as follow :

```
  List<bool> isSelected = [false, false, false];
  FocusNode focusNodeButton1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeButton2 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeButton3 = FocusNode();
  List<FocusNode> focusToggle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    focusToggle = [focusNodeButton1, focusNodeButton2, focusNodeButton3];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    focusNodeButton1.dispose();
    focusNodeButton2.dispose();
    focusNodeButton3.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: kDefaultPadding / 2),
              child: ToggleButtons(
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                selectedBorderColor: kMaincolor,
                selectedColor: kMaincolor,
                focusNodes: focusToggle,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lingkar Teman",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Orang Lain",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Semua",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                isSelected: isSelected,
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. The possible issue can be you wrote `isSelected` list after running the app and now you are trying to hot reload the app so it's taking it as `null` and this issue is happening. Please try to restart the app or initialize the `isSelected` in build. Moreover you cannot revert the state of array just like that as you need to check the index. You can replace `setState()` content as the following

```dart
setState(() {
    for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
        isSelected[i] = i == index
    }
});
```